# Cannot import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm making a Spark (2.2.0) Streaming project with using Scala 2.11.11, SBT 0.13.15 and Kafka 0.10.2.1 on Intelij IDEA 2017.2. So far I've been able import other streaming modules like `org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext` and `org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds`, but for some reason my project won't recognize `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._` even though I do believe I've the right library dependencies:

```
name := "ProjectName"

version := "1.0"

resolvers += "Apache repo" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases"

val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.10.2.1",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-to-slf4j" % "2.8.2",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j" % "2.8.2" pomOnly(),
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test"
)
```

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.10.2.1"
```

Isn't the right dependency. You need:

```
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % sparkVersion
```

Comment: Actually I need the first dependency because I'm using scala to access `KafkaProducer` and `KafkaConsumer`. But yeah the second dependency is what I needed for kafka/spark-streaming imports.

Comment: @user2361174 Can you elaborate why you need to access `KafkaProducer` and `KafkaConsumer` inside a streaming job? Out of interest..

Comment: I'm using `KafkaProducer` to send data (generated either in the program or send via some API) into a topic, at the same time the spark stream recognizes these new messages and includes them in the next batch and processes it. The `KafkaConsumer` be used to send the messages into a database for later usage.